# Which database should I use with node.js?

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb, phpmyadmin, database

Which database should I use with node.js? I'm condering MySQL and MONGO DB.

Comment: Some might say that since both MongoDB and Node use JavaScript, they are a natural fit for each other. Others will be screaming that NoSQL databases are a recipe for disaster. This is a very opinionated topic, so I'm afraid you'll have to decide on your own.

Comment: If you were me, then what would you have decided?

Comment: Can you tell us about the project or how you intend to use the database? Mongo and Mysql are very different and are good at different things, so it depends on what you're doing more than a technology synergy thing.

Comment: It depends on your project.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The correct answer is: it depends.

Like many other programming languages node has various adapters for databases. Ture, some are better than others, but they are all changing and evolving so fast that any statement here would be outdated soon. Even if you select one database, you will find at least two or three adapters with different qualities.

In the end it does not really matter what is a good fit for Node, but what is a good fit for your project. Trying to squeeze a relational problem into a NoSQL storage will do you no good.

The node community provides you with lots of possibilities. Take a look at the [Node Toolbox](http://nodetoolbox.com/) to find some solutions for CouchDB, MongoDB, Redis, Database abstraction layers, MySQL, … As always you need a bit of common sense to choose the right module. Look at commit history, how many maintainers, activity, last commit timestamp, issue queue, etc. You will surely find a solution for a database that you are comfortable with.

I personally find it rather overwhelming when I have to learn more than one technology at once. So if you are new to node, I would rather stick to a database you know for your first project.

Comment: ok thanks, for my first project i would use mysql and then will try to use mongo db when i will have some command over node.js.

Answer (score 2):

Every one has different requirements for completion so it really depends on what you are trying to do. Like Joseph said `MongoDB` and `Node.js` works really well together but for certain use case, `MySQL` could probably be a better choice. Also, you might want to considered the database you are the most comfortable with. Personnaly, I would recommand `MongoDB` but I think it's a matter of preference.