# What database is the most compatible with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Currently, I am building a web site with Node.js. I am familiar with MySQL. But I have found that someone said that MySQL module for Node.js was buggy and not compatible well with Node.js. So I wonder any database that is the most compatible with Node.js. Is mongodb a good choice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The one that has a library written for it? Seriously, though, if you can write SQL then you can use node to interact with pretty much any SQL db since the interaction is decoupled through SQL. MongoDB uses a Javascript-like syntax so it will look more like the rest of your code, but that doesn't make it more compatible.

Comment: Googling `What database is the most compatible with Node.js?` gives me e.g. this:  [Which database to use with node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14265649)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm using MongoDB with my Node.js apps every time. This is easy and elegant, because Mongo has similar syntax to the other parts of the application.
For example, this method retrieves some entries of a selected user:

```
exports.entries = function (req, res) {
    var user_id = parseInt(req.params.user_id);

    db.collection('entries', function(err, collection) {
        collection.find({user_id: user_id}).toArray(
            function(err, entries) {
                res.json({
                    entries: entries
                });
            }
        );
    });
};
```

Also the MongoDB driver is written in pure JavaScript and provides a native asynchronous Node.js interface to MongoDB that makes it really fast.

Comment: How about relational db?

Answer (score 4):

"Which db use with node" is probably not the right question. However, lacking your DB requirements here is a list of pros and cons from my experience:

- Drivers support: PostrgreSQL, Mysql, Mongo, CouchDB have good drivers with lots of users and application in production. Oracle and MSSQL drivers have much less users in node ecosystem and you are on your own if you have problems (things getting better here, there is MS developed driver but you locked to Windows)
- Trends: PostgreSQL as generic db, Mysql if you have legacy db, redis/leveldb for key/value / cache type of data, mongo for datasets you expect not to grow bigger than few GBs.
- Universal advice: pick DB you know well. Node.js drivers are less of a problem than proper DB architecture / backups / data integrity / replications / failovers etc.

Answer (score 1):

This question should be answered more by how you plan to query the data than by which database to use with a particular application stack.  See the opening parts of this [blog post](http://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/).

Your question is a bit like asking, "Should I buy a hammer or a screwdriver?"  I don't know-- do you need to drive in nails or screws?

If this is just a toy project for learning purposes, I'd probably just go with MongoDB.